# Tracking of Mir space station backwards in time?

Tags: space-station, tracking, orbital-elements, mir, ephemeris

Is there a site with the tracking information for the old space station Mir? Or some place with the data location tracking information still available? Maybe even a site with orbital mechanics backwards in time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[CelesTrack](https://celestrak.org) has Mir ephemerides (as [TLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set), two-line element sets) in its [NORAD Two-Line Element Sets Historical Archives](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/archives/). It's a 755 KB in size ZIP archive ([direct link](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/archives/mir.zip)) packing a text file with 22,333 TLE spanning time period from February 19, 1986 to March 23, 2001 when it was [deorbited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir#Final_days_and_deorbit). If these don't go far enough back in time for your needs, you can request even earlier TLE by filling and submitting [this form](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/archives/request.asp) (use *16609* as Mir's 5-digit NORAD catalog number).